# iOS 15 Communication Notification picture not shown

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification, wwdc, ios15

I've been trying to update my (local & push) notifications to Communication notifications.

When a user receives a communication event from one of their friend, I want the displayed notification to include the friend's profile picture. Just like the new iMessage app does.

After watching the dedicated WWDC2021 session, I added a Siri Intent to my SwiftUI app:

```
// I correctly added the StartCallIntent to both my app's Info.plist and the Siri Intent extension.
<array>
    <string>INStartCallIntent</string>
</array>
```

and tried to update my notification flow with the following:

```swift
let image = INImage(imageData: friend.profilePicture.cellImage.pngData()!)
let intentFriend = INPerson(
  personHandle: INPersonHandle(value: friend.phoneNumber, type: .phoneNumber),
  nameComponents: friend.nameComponents,
  displayName: friend.localName,
  image: image,
  contactIdentifier: nil,
  customIdentifier: nil,
  isMe: false,
  suggestionType: .instantMessageAddress
)

let incomingCommunicationIntent = INStartCallIntent(
  callRecordFilter: nil,
  callRecordToCallBack: nil,
  audioRoute: .unknown,
  destinationType: .normal,
  contacts: [intentFriend],
  callCapability: .audioCall
)

let interaction = INInteraction(intent: incomingCommunicationIntent, response: nil)
interaction.direction = .incoming
interaction.donate(completion: nil)

do {
  let result = try notification.updating(from: incomingCommunicationIntent)
  return result
} catch let error {
  print("-- \(error)")
  // TODO: Handle error here
}

return notification
```

The returned `UNNotificationContent` is then handled to be displayed either as a push notification or a local one.

While the above code doesn't crash and seems to /work/, the notification doesn't look any different.
Looking with a debugger, the `_UNNotificationCommunicationContext` is initialized, but:

- `_displayName` is nil
- `_recipients` is empty (as expected)
- `_contentURL` is nil
- `_attachments` is empty
- `sender` is set to a `UNNotificationContact` on which

  - `handle` & `displayName` are correctly set
  - `_handleType` seems correctly set too

In the app's logs, I can see:

```
[Intents] -[INCache cacheableObjectForIdentifier:] Unable to find cacheable object with identifier EDB29166-E46A-CF23-AB27-8B61F763A039 in cache.
[Intents] -[INCache cacheableObjectForIdentifier:] Unable to find cacheable object with identifier intents-remote-image-proxy:?proxyIdentifier=EDB29166-E46A-CF23-AB27-8B61F763A039.png&storageServiceIdentifier=com.apple.Intents.INImageServiceConnection in cache.
```

What am I missing to correctly display the friend's profile picture?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately Apple did not do a great job at documenting communication notifications, their WWDC video leaves a ton of very important details out, but there are a few things:

1. In your Notification Service Extension's `Info.plist` you need to add this:
   `NSExtension` -> `NSExtensionAttributes` (dict) -> `IntentsSupported` (array) -> `INSendMessageIntent` or `INStartCallIntent`.
2. Make sure you enabled the "Communication Notifications" capability on your main app target.
3. Finally, your code looks right but you need to add this (note: I have only tested this for `INSendMessageIntent`)

```
// Swift
incomingCommunicationIntent.setImage(image, forParameterNamed: \.sender)

// Objective-C
[incomingCommunicationIntent setImage:image forParameterNamed:"sender"];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
There is a slight mistake with the Swift code, I guess you wanted to simply type `\.sender`

Also, I had issues because I was running iOS 15 Beta 2. When I upgraded to Beta 4, everything started working.

Out of curiosity, how did you find this solution? Trial/guess ?

Comment: Thanks nightsd01! Also I found that in testing on iOS 15 Beta 6, initializing `INImage` with image data works great, but not when initializing with a remote image url.

Comment: @owjsub If you are dispatching async the code will exit the function and will not execute the completion. Make sure you dispatch sync.

Comment: I've done all of the above, but still getting the "unable to find object with identifier in cache" error.

Comment: @johnnykehr Here's a [great gist with a Swift example](https://gist.github.com/Dexwell/dedef7389eae26c5b9db927dc5588905), by [@Dexwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543717/dexwell)
It's also worth noting the above solution seems to work starting from iOS 15 **Beta 4**

Comment: Thanks for this! As I mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69552911/673745 you can use `incomingCommunicationIntent.setImage(image, forParameterNamed: \.speakableGroupName)` to show the group image in group messages :D

Comment: @johnnykehr I'm in the same situation you was in. Do you have any resolution on communication notification with remote image URL? Thanks

Comment: @AlexTerente could you please specify in code what that means. I can not figure out how to display an image from a remote url. Whatever i tried it did not show up ...

Answer (score 1):

For those who's confused like I was, the `INSendMessageIntent` key has to be added under `NSUserActivityTypes` in the plist file in the main target, like this:

```
<key>NSUserActivityTypes</key>
<array>
  <string>INSendMessageIntent</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who has problems with URL inutializing use this:

```swift
extension INImage {
    convenience init?(contentsOf url: URL) {
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            self.init(imageData: data)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

It feels like workaround, but works.

Found it somhere on web, but lost the source, sry