# Using a group icon with iOS 15 communication notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, sirikit, ios15

I have followed the instructions in [this great Gist](https://gist.github.com/Dexwell/dedef7389eae26c5b9db927dc5588905) to get a `INSendMessageIntent` working to display the user's profile image on iOS 15. And it works great.

However, I am unable to figure out how to get the image for a group message to be displayed.

I cannot get it to simultaneously show both the group name and an icon for it. If I don't provide the group as an INPerson in `recipients` then `speakableGroupName` will not appear in the notification UI. But the `INImage` on the group's `INPerson` is never displayed, nor is the sender's image when I do this.

iMessage seems to show the group icon as well as the group name, so it seems possible with this API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68705169/673745 gave me the idea to make this work. You need to pass at least 2 recipients (I used the current user and the sender), then do this and it works!

```
// Swift
sendMessageIntent.setImage(image, forParameterNamed: \.speakableGroupName)

// Objective-C
[sendMessageIntent setImage:image forParameterNamed:"speakableGroupName"];
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work...

Comment: @WilGieseler do you have at least 2 recipients? (you could have `miPerson` and `senderPerson`, for example)

Comment: Yes, this turned out to be the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yay! I'm glad it worked :D I updated my original response to reflect that too!